SharePoint Online page - Saved Date field
I have some pages that I am updating in sharepoint and I would like to know how I can get the edited/updated date to display on the page like:
Updated: <Updated date, DD Month YYYY>
I would like to do this so that a person looking at the information can clearly see when the information was last updated without having to navigate away from the page or go into settings. Some users will only have view access.
I am reluctant to create a new 'list' for each page as there are hundreds of them and I am currently manually adding in the updated date.
I have also tried with the code on this page: Show Last Modified Date in Wiki page
I don't think that I embedded it properly or it might be missing something as when I pasted the code in it just had the code and not the modified date.
any help would be greatly appreciated.

I can see the Published date of a page in the command bar.

@teylyn ... blinks. I can't seem to see it. I am pretty new to sharepoint though.

use modern pages. Wiki pages are legacy. Avoid these if you want current SharePoint online functionality.

A modern page shows the last published date in the command bar at the top right.

I haven't seen a scenario where a person who can edit a page does NOT see that, but I have not checked for legacy wiki and web part pages.

Okay ... I think we have the 365 Sharepoint, but I am working with a Wiki created by a colleague.
What is the differences between modern pages and old 'wiki' style?

The difference is a whole new concept of web pages that are not compatible. Wiki pages are a legacy leftover from SharePoint on premises. They support interlinking between pages with special characters, and the whole page is one big editing canvas. Modern SharePoint online pages have sections and new, modern web parts that are different from the legacy web parts..
